# can't install software using brew on my mac?

Tags: macos, homebrew, cpython, libtool

I'm using brew to install some software and when I try to install the software I get this:

```
localhost:~ timger$ brew install autoconf
Error: No available formula for autoconf
localhost:~ timger$ brew install automake
Error: No available formula for automake
localhost:~ timger$ brew install libtool
Error: No available formula for libtool
localhost:~ timger$ brew install pkg-con
```

Answer (score 6):

All of the things you're trying to install are part of the Xcode command-line tools package, other than `pkg-config`, which you misspelled.

Install Xcode from the App Store, then install the "Command Line Tools" package from the Downloads tab of the Xcode preferences.